# What is the requirements to fly from CA to TX

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, passports, identity-cards

I'm an immigrant living in US for 5 years now

Now I want to travel from San Francisco, California to Houston, Texas

I have green card, passport from Vietnam and driver license.

Do I need visa or another passport to be able to do this?

Answer (score 5):

@dunni's answer is technically correct, but let me amplify. The United States is one country and there has not been a need for a visa or permit to go from one state to another, ever. (OK: except crossing military lines during the Civil War.) You need identification to get on an airplane flight. [Acceptable forms](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) include either your passport *or* your Green Card. The status of drivers licenses is changing, as some states' licenses will be deemed insufficiently secure. California will has just [started](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/newsrel/2018/2018_01) offering Real ID, but your existing license probably does not qualify and will not be accepted after October 1, 2020.

Comment: It has been brought to my attention that restrictions on internal movement were placed on people of Japanese (especially! they were interned), German, and Italian descent during WW2. For purposes of the travel answer, no change.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't leave the USA by having a stopover in another country, while flying to Texas, your existing green card and passport are enough (not sure, if the driving license alone would be sufficient as identification, i read something about some changes there). But with the passport and green card you are definitely fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but flying from CA to TX with a CA or TX driver's license alone is perfectly fine. That's often the only thing Americans have.

Comment: @RobertColumbia perhaps because a passport and a green card are far more than enough.  Why bring the passport and risk losing it when it's entirely unnecessary?

Comment: @Dennis but permanent residents are required by law to carry their green cards, and two of the very few airports in the US where one actually might run into trouble for this (by encountering Border Patrol officers at the TSA checkpoint) are in Texas, McAllen and Brownsville.  So it would be a good idea to bring the green card.

Comment: Whether or not it is required or not, having your green card is likely to be *very* helpful if you get stopped and questioned about your immigration status. You can just check in and fly with your driver's license and keep your green card tucked away in case you are asked for it.